# Powershell starts with an error message when opened by context menu in folder

Tags: python-3.x, powershell

I only use powershell to open my jupyter notebook.

However, I am having this error when I open powershell from a folder.

```
The string is missing the terminator: '.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

I tried resetting my PowerShell as described here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qbOGMzu3X9I

But this did not work. I also follow the conversation here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bf3344de-3af6-48e3-9f43-f595bb41c62d/bug-powershell-starts-w-error-when-opened-by-context-menu-in-folder-w-apostrophe-in-its-name?forum=win10itprogeneral

Again, I failed to understand how to do this step by step. I think it would be helpful if some expert can help non-professional programmers to understand the steps they need to do so that when we open PowerShell from a particular folder we are not greeted with "The string is missing the terminator:"

PowerShell fails to get the **full path of the folder PowerShell** was opened into and it just goes back to the folder where the PowerShell executable is "C:\WINDOWS\system32"

Comment: So, you need help figuring out how to inspect and/or edit a registry key value at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Powershell\command`?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help out, No not exactly. I went there and was unable to change powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location -literalPath '%V'

What shall I change it to? 
powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location -literalPath "%V"

Comment: Is it possible for you to remove the apostrophe (') from the folder name?  Otherwise, perhaps change the apostrophe to a back-tick (\`)?  There are other similar substitute characters that might work, but an apostrophe in the folder name will produce this error when opening PowerShell from File > Open Windows PowerShell from Windows explorer.  Another work-around is simply to navigate into the folder, then in Windows explorer's address bar, type-in `powershell`, then press [Enter].  You should be able to open PowerShell in the folder (with an apostrophe) without that error.  Hope this helps.